# PHP session is lost after submit

Tags: php, session

This makes no sense. It works in localhost, but not in my server.

Before submiting the form, if I `var_dump()` the `$_SESSION` it retrieves me the following:

```
array(2) { ["email"]=> string(40) "082b6eff9db5019e6a28f586a679b7f72fab27f4" ["id"]=> int(5) }
```

The form is this one:

```
<form method='POST' action='response.php?type=add_customer'>
    <input type='text' name='customer'/>
    <input type='submit' value='add'/>
</form>
```

If I `var_dump()` the `$_SESSION` on **response.php** I get: `array(0) { }`

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

How d'hell is this possible?

Because it works localhost but not in my server..could it be a php.ini problem? If so, what?

**EDIT (1)**: Changed my code to this (in **response.php**):

```
session_start();

if(isset($_REQUEST['type'])){
    switch ($_REQUEST['type']){
       case 'add_customer': 
        var_dump($_SESSION);
        break;
    }
}
```

Continues not to work. It retrieves an empty array.

**EDIT (2): Solved.**
If someone could explain to me why this:

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION); // doesn't work
print_r($_SESSION); // doesn't work
echo $_SESSION['id']; // works
```

I appreciate. Because the problem was this.

Comment: check session_save_path in php.ini...

Comment: Try without the condition, `if(!isset($_SESSION)){` just put `session_start();` not sure why your doing this...

Comment: your this code `if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }
var_dump($_SESSION);` makes no sense . You never user start_session() after checking $_SESSION . Infact you cannot use $_SESSION without session_start() at the top of script . I don't know how it is working on your localhost

Comment: @LozCherone and 'Lets Code' see my edited post please.

Comment: @user1844933, my server has the following structure:
`/home/project/public_html`
`/home/project/public_ftp`
`/home/project/www`  

In none of them I see php.ini. Can I add the file to one of the folders?

Comment: <?php phpinfo(); ?> create one php file with this code and run, you will get php.ini config

Comment: @user1844933 the output of session.save_path: `session.save_path /tmp /tmp`

Answer (score 3):

Put `session_start();` as the first thing after the `<?php` tag at the top of every page were you want your `$_SESSION` data to persist

Comment: try removing the if completely and just var_dump POST, GET, REQUEST & SESSION to see what is being sent

Comment: I've changed my response.php file to only this: <?php session_start(); var_dump($_SESSION); exit(); ?> and it continues to retrieve me array {0}. I've checked chrome cookies and I have 6 cookies in my website including the PHPSESSID. I enter directly to the URL: mywebsite.com/response.php (without submiting the form), and I receive array {0} too

Answer (score 0):

Not good to combine GET and POST. Update your form to the following

```
<form method="POST" action="response.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="add_customer" />
    <input type="text" name="customer" />
    <input type="submit" value="add" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

put these two lines in both your pages. (right after the opening < ? php tag at the very to of your page, before any includes, before any output (empty spaces, bom characters, etc)
Under normal conditions, these should print exactly the same.

Now, since your second page does not have any session variables, i am guessing that the sessions are not set. So my best guess is that something is blocking/preventing your sessions or deletes/unset them.

Are you sure that you don't load/include anything above the following line?

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['type'])){
```

**EDIT 1:** Lets try someting:
Create folder sessions in your www directory. Set permissions to 777 for starters.

```
<?php
session_save_path('/home/project/www/sessions');
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

Put above code on top of page and check if you get anything

Comment: I've changed my response.php file to only this:
`<?php session_start(); 
   var_dump($_SESSION);
   exit();
?>` and it continues to retrieve me array {0}. I've checked chrome cookies and I have 6 cookies in my website including the PHPSESSID.

I enter directly to the URL: http://mywebsite.com/response.php (without submiting the form), and I receive array {0} too.

Comment: @user3243925 nope - no idea why 3rd solution work. Totally mind confusing.

Comment: me too. I also have created another blank page only with that code and it's the same..seriously, I don't get it.

Comment: @user3243925 perhaps they (server admin) save the sessions in server temp folders not as arrays/superglobals but as string? its weird. Anyway, good you found a working solution. You can contact them also to try to figure out what is wrong in their set up and provide them with a working example of the problem.